# constant field of a divisor 

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $D$ be a divisor on a smooth, projective algebraic variety $X$ of dimension n over a field $k$ and let $D_j$ be an irreducible component of $D$.

I came across the expression *the constant field of* $D_j$ and I'm trying to understand its meaning.

Here is my guess: as $D_j$ is irreducible, it has a (unique) generic point $\eta_i$. Let's look at the residue field $k(\eta_i)$

**(Aside) question**: is it true that $\Gamma(D_j, \mathcal{O}_{D_j})=k(\eta_i)?$

The residue field $k(\eta_i)$ is of the form $k_i(T_1,...,T_{n-1})$ and $k_i$ is the constant field.

Am I right?

**Question**: How do you show that $k_i$ a finite extension of $k$?

Can someone give me any precise reference to this staff (by precise I mean not just "look at Hartshorne")

Comment: The answer to the first question is no: `$\Gamma(D,\mathcal O_D)$`, where $D$ is a projective variety (or scheme) over $k$, is a finite extension of $k$.

And why do you say that `$k(\eta_i)$` is a field of rational dunctions? The divisor `$D_j$` need not be a rational variety.

Comment: Thanks Serge. So everything was wrong... Then, is it $\Gamma(D, \mathcal{O}_D)$ what is called the constant field? Can you give me some precise reference to study this? 

Comment: How do you prove that it is a finite extension?